# Electron Nightmare.js NodeList to Array

Tags: node.js, electron, nightmare, nodelist

I'm trying to iterate through a NodeList obtained via Nightmare.js. Executing in the dev tools performs as expected, but in ElectronI can't convert the NodeList to array successfully.

```html
   nightmare
  .goto('https://www.somePage.com')
  .wait('#someID')
  .evaluate(function () {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('div.someClass')
    return links;
  })
  .end()
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log(result); // outputs the NodeList successfully. 
    var nodesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(result);
    console.log(nodesArray.length) // Always 0 
    })
   .catch(function (error) {
      console.error('Failed', 
      error);
    })
```

I've tried porting the NodeList by various other methods. Nothing seams to work in Electron. Again, this is easily achieved in chrome tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that HTMLElements or Nodes are valid in the context of the page. Anything that needs to be passed from evaluate() to then(), is internally sent using nightmare.ipc module. This means that returned value is converted to string (JSON.stringify) and then created back.

If you check Developer console logs then you would see conversion errors.

You can evaluate length in the evaluate function itself and pass it.

```
nightmare
  .goto(url)
  .evaluate(function(selector) {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll(selector)
    return links.length;
  }, selector)
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result); // Outputs length.
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error('Failed', error);
  });
```

In case you need to pass elements in different evaluate() steps then you can have workaround for it, but that is different story